# laravel session [] operator not supported for strings

Tags: php, session, laravel-5

I am trying to append value in existing session with request data,
but i am getting `[] operator not supported for strings` error.

The request data is string.

Here is whole code,

```
    if(Session::has('cart')) {
        Session::push('cart',$request->id);

    } else Session::set('cart',$request->id);
```

Comment: what is the value in the session for `cart` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Session::push` - Push A Value Onto An Array Session Value.

In cart you have string not array.

```
# Remove old `string` value.
Session::forget('cart');

if(Session::has('cart')) {
    Session::push('cart', $request->id);
} else {
    Session::set('cart', array($request->id));
}
```

With string value in session you don't need to use `push` method, just use `set`, `has`, `get`